# Chrome connect to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome-extension

i did an chrome extension that connects to mysql and then shows the results.

I have got the scrip (ajax.js, consulta.php and consulta_empleados.html). It works when i go from  `http://localhost/ajax/consulta_empleados.html` but when i execute the extension it doesn't show me the results, it shows me the php code and it would have that show the query result.

See this:
[image]

How i can do this?

Here codes (simple ajax and php):

manifest

```js
{
"name": "demo",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Making your first Google Chrome extension.",
"icons":{
    "128":"icon_128.png"
},

"browser_action":   {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "consulta_empleados.html"
}
```

}

consulta_empleados.html

```
<html>

    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <title>Consulta Registro con AJAX</title>


  <!-- referenciamos al archivo ajax.js donde se encuentra nuestra funcion objetoAjax-->

    <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>

    </head>


    <body onLoad="MostrarConsulta('consulta.php')">



  <div id="resultado"></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

ajax.js

```
// JavaScript Document function objetoAjax(){
        var xmlhttp=false;
        try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
                try {
                   xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (E) {
                        xmlhttp = false;
                }
        }

        if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        return xmlhttp; }

function MostrarConsulta(datos){
        divResultado = document.getElementById('resultado');
        ajax=objetoAjax();
        ajax.open("GET", datos);
        ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
                if (ajax.readyState==4) {
                        divResultado.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
                }
        }
        ajax.send(null) }
```

consulta.php

```
<?php //Configuracion de la conexion a base de datos $bd_host = "localhost";  $bd_usuario = "root";  $bd_password = "";  $bd_base = "tic"; 

$con = mysql_connect($bd_host, $bd_usuario, $bd_password); 

mysql_select_db($bd_base, $con); 

//consulta todos los empleados

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM usuarios",$con);

//muestra los datos consultados echo "</p>Nombres </p>"; while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        //echo "<p>".$row['nombres']." - ".$row['departamento']." - ".$row['sueldo']."</p> n";      echo "<p>".$row['name']."</p>"; } ?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well. The actual answer is: this happens because you try to load "consulta.php" relative to your extension's base URL. And your php-code can be executed only if it's called from http: // localhost/... but not chrome-extension://yourExtensionId/...

Second - there is no need to implement ActiveX object to obtain XMLHttpRequest object - you can just use **new XMLHttpRequest** in Google Chrome.

Comment: and how i can do it? Because i tryed to change localhost for my ip but it's the same.

Comment: You can change *onLoad="MostrarConsulta('consulta.php')* to *onLoad="MostrarConsulta('http: // localhost/path/to/consulta.php')*.

Comment: @user1446242 As Dmitry said, you can't execute PHP from extension because PHP is a server script, it need a interpreter.

Comment: @DmitrySorin That won't work because for security reason, XHR did not work for a cross-domain URL.

Comment: mm.. and an easy way to do the sql request ?

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0):

You need a server on your network or a online server for the data, and then set permission on manifest.json for your server.

First, delete 'consulta.php' file of the extension because this file won't work by it self, so you don't need it into the extension.

Then, you can edit other file like this:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "demo",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Making your first Google Chrome extension.",
  "icons": {
      "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "consulta_empleados.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "http://localhost/"
  ]
}
```

**consulta_empleados.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Consulta Registro con AJAX</title>
<script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="resultado"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I removed the body `onload` event because:

> Refused to execute inline event handler because of
>   Content-Security-Policy.

**ajax.js**

```
window.onload = function() {
  var XHR = new XMLHttpRequest;
  XHR.open('GET', 'http://localhost/consulta.php', true);
  XHR.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (4 == this.readyState) {
      var status = this.status;
      if (400 > status) {
        var responseText = this.responseText;
        if (responseText) {
          document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = responseText;
        }
      }
    }
  };
  XHR.send();
}
```

Here we use `window.onload` to load the data, and we need to use XMLHttpRequest because we can't load external script dynamically or this will prompt:

> Refused to load script from
>   'http://localhost/consulta.php' because of
>   Content-Security-Policy.

Finally, edit your server 'consulta.php' like this:

**consulta.php**

```
<?php
// Configuracion de la conexion a base de datos
define('MYSQL_HOST', 'localhost');
define('MYSQL_USER', 'root');
define('MYSQL_PASS', '');
define('MYSQL_DB', 'tic');

$con = mysql_connect(MYSQL_HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS);
mysql_select_db(MYSQL_DB, $con);

// Consulta todos los empleados
$sql = mysql_query('SELECT `name` FROM `usuarios`', $con);

// Almacena los datos consultados en una matriz
$output = array('<p>Nombres</p>');
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
  $output[] = '<p>' . $row['nombres'] . ' - ' . $row['departamento'] . ' - ' . $row['sueldo'] . '</p><p>' . $row['name'] . '</p>';
}

// Imprimir los datos directamente
echo implode('', $output);
?>
```

And you got this:

[image: Screenshot]

**Remember change the server URL into 'ajax.js' file.**

---

**UPDATE:**

As a lot of answer in other posts said, you should use PDO instead MySQL extension, because [MySQL extension is deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) so the new code for **consulta.php** is like this:

```
<?php
// Configuracion de la conexion a base de datos
define('PDO_DSN', 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=tic');
define('PDO_USER', 'root');
define('PDO_PASS', '');

$pdo = new PDO(PDO_DSN, PDO_USER, PDO_PASS);

// Consulta todos los empleados
$query = $pdo->query('SELECT `name` FROM `usuarios`');

// Almacena los datos consultados en una matriz
$output = array('<p>Nombres</p>');
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  $output[] = '<p>' . $row['nombres'] . ' - ' . $row['departamento'] . ' - ' . $row['sueldo'] . '</p><p>' . $row['name'] . '</p>';
}

unset($pdo, $query);

// Imprimir los datos directamente
echo implode('', $output);
?>
```

Comment: It doesn't show anything. I tried with extension and directly from the server path (localhost/path...).

Comment: if i go to http://localhost/path/consulta.php it shows me:

MostrarDatos('
Nombres

demo

demo2

')

Comment: I just added an new example using PDO instead function of MySQL extension, you can found the same recommendation message in [PHP manual site](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: @user1446242 Ok, there are something wrong, your SQL query only requested `name` but on the row you request the result of 'nombre', 'departamento', 'sueldo' and 'name'... That's weird.

Comment: to finish.. the last question. Why when i execute it, it shows me the result out of the square ? See the image http://www.imagebanana.com/view/hj2a90qi/chrfome.jpg

Comment: @user1446242 I updated the post again because my old method does not work with the newest Google Chrome on the issue of security policy.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change this line:

```
// Imprimir funcion de javascript 'MostrarDatos()'
echo "MostrarDatos('", implode('', $output), "')";
```

to

```
// Imprimir funcion de javascript 'MostrarConsulta()'
echo "MostrarConsulta('", implode('', $output), "')";
```